# Solidify 3d slice thin walls

Tags: cloth-simulation, 3d-printing, solidify-modifier

[image]I drape the barrels with a subdivided mesh and apply subdivide.
All works fine.
I solidify with .05 thickness and apply.
Most of the draped mesh thickens except the top where it lays across barrels.
Export as STL which confirms the top is a lot thinner than the sides.
I am missing a setting somewhere, any help please.
Eddy

Comment: Did you apply scale in object mode?

Comment: Thank you Marty, just one simple step and all is good lots to learn.